# How to configure view filter to search on the basis of two conditions

Tags: views

I have created a view for users which is having filters: Username,Email,Company and Country. I am also using views bulk operation with these filters.

I can search any record on the basis of above fields but the problem is to search the record on two conditions.

For Example: I want to search on the basis of email: I want the record of those users whose accounts are neither in gmail nor in yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

You can add filters twice.  So, to avoid getting gmail or yahoo, you can first add a NOT gmail e-mail filter, and then add a second NOT yahoo filter.

This is not a great way to do it if you have an extremely large number of requirements, but if you only have a few, then it should be fine.

Comment: The Solution was fine but the problem is i need some solution which must be filter data twice that is it should filter data twice first on gmail then on yahoo like this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: I am filtering data using views for the users but i needed functionality like admin/people where i can filter data first time on the basis of email id which does not end with gmail.com and after on the generated result i will again filter on the basis of email where condition is does not end with yahho.com.

Comment: So you want to apply the not-gmail filter and then the not-yahoo filter, instead of having both filters applied at the same time?

Comment: Yes exactly i want the same.

Comment: Use this answer, then expose your filter so you can make a choice which ones are applied to results.